# Return dynamic arrays by ref in Swig

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, swig

I'm using swig to wrap some code in c++ to use in Python.
I have a function that get array and return 2 dynamic arrays (the function get them by ref) after some calculation on the input array.
My problem is that the output arrays are unspecified size, because the size depends on the input array.
My Function look like:

```
void arrayManipulate(int* inArray, int inLen, int resolution, int* &outArray1, int &outLen1, int* &outArray2, int &outLen2)
```

I used numpy.i to cast the input array to numpy array.
But if I want to use numpy to return the array with ARGOUT it does not work, because it assume the size of the output array is known.

module.i:

```
%module minimal
%{
#include "minimal.h"
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
%}

%include numpy.i
%init %{
inport_array();
%}
%apply (int* INARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* inArray, int inLen)}
%apply (int* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* &outArray1, int &outLen1), (int* &outArray2, int &outLen2)
%include "minimal.h"
```

If I try to compile this, i get the folowing error:

```
File minimal_wrap.cxx: IntelliSense: a value of type "int" could not be assigned to entity od type "int *"
File minimal_wrap.cxx: IntelliSense: a value of type "int *" could not be assigned to entity od type "int **"
```

If I remove all the "&" signs from the minimal.i and minimal.h (from the function), it compile but excepct python to give the dimension of the output arrays:

```
TypeError: arrayManipulate takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I want to use it in python somthing like:

```
import minimal
import numpy as np
arr1, arr2 = minimal.arrayManipulate(np.asarray([1,2,3]),100)
```

How can i make it works?

Comment: It looks like you need the `ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1` typemap.

Comment: Change your signature to `(int* inArray, int inLen, int resolution, int** outArray1, int* outLen1, int** outArray2, int *outLen2)` and use `ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1` or even better `ARGOUTVIEWM_ARRAY1`. The return a NumPy array with managed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes an answer, which uses double pointers rather than *&. You can make a simple wrapper function to support this prototype

Please note that the returned arrays are allocated and the typemap generates a proxy which ensures that the arrays are deleted when deleted in Python. They are managed

Header file (test.h):

```
#pragma once

void fun(int* inArray, int inLen, int resolution,
     int** outArray1, int* outLen1,
     int** outArray2, int* outLen2);
```

Source file (test.cpp):

```
#include "test.h"
#include <malloc.h>

void fun(int* inArray, int inLen, int resolution, 
     int** outArray1, int* outLen1,
     int** outArray2, int* outLen2) {

  int _outLen1 = resolution*inLen;
  int _outLen2 = resolution*inLen;
  int* _outArray1 = (int*)malloc(_outLen1*sizeof(int));
  int* _outArray2 = (int*)malloc(_outLen2*sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0 ; i < inLen ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < resolution ; j++) {
      _outArray1[i*resolution+j] = resolution*inArray[i];
      _outArray2[i*resolution+j] = resolution*inArray[i];
    }
  }

  // Assign outputs
  *outLen1 = _outLen1;
  *outLen2 = _outLen2;
  *outArray1 = _outArray1;
  *outArray2 = _outArray2;
}
```

Interface definition file (test.i)

```
%module example
%{
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
  #include "test.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init
%{
  import_array();
%}

%apply (int* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* inArray, int inLen)}

%apply (int** ARGOUTVIEWM_ARRAY1, int* DIM1) {(int** outArray1, int* outLen1)}
%apply (int** ARGOUTVIEWM_ARRAY1, int* DIM1) {(int** outArray2, int* outLen2)}

%include "test.h"
```

from within Python

```
import numpy as np
import example
a = np.ones(27,dtype=np.int32)
h = example.fun(a,2) # h contains the two outputs
```

To support e.g. size_t, search for this section in numpy.i

```
%numpy_typemaps(unsigned long long, NPY_ULONGLONG, int)
%numpy_typemaps(float             , NPY_FLOAT    , int)
%numpy_typemaps(double            , NPY_DOUBLE   , int)
```

and add the following

```
%numpy_typemaps(signed char       , NPY_BYTE     , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(unsigned char     , NPY_UBYTE    , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(short             , NPY_SHORT    , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(unsigned short    , NPY_USHORT   , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(int               , NPY_INT      , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(unsigned int      , NPY_UINT     , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(long              , NPY_LONG     , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(unsigned long     , NPY_ULONG    , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(long long         , NPY_LONGLONG , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(unsigned long long, NPY_ULONGLONG, size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(float             , NPY_FLOAT    , size_t)
%numpy_typemaps(double            , NPY_DOUBLE   , size_t)
```

This add more typemaps to support indexing using size_t rather than int.

Comment: That works for me. Thank you. If I want the type of the dimension argument (outLen1) to be different then int - long or size_t for large arrays, how do i do that?

Comment: Add a few lines in numpy.i. All typemaps are created using a macro. Look into the file